# Access a Static File Located in Symfony Bundle

Tags: symfony

How can we access a html file located inside Bundle folder.?

Refer attached screen

1. Possible with controller.?
2. Possible with out controller.?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Controller Access**

You can access to the root dir thanks to this :

```
$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
```

It will place into `app/` directory and then you can navigate as you want

So in your case I think this will be work:

```
$fileToYourPath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../src/C2Educate/ToolsBundle/Stripe/c2/c2.html'
```

**Service Access**

You can access to the root dir by injecting container (dependency injection pattern)

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface; 

class MyClass
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function doWhatever()
    {
        $root = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir();

        $fileToYourPath = $root.'/../src/C2Educate/ToolsBundle/Stripe/c2/c2.html'

    }
}
```

In your services.yml, define your new service:

```
myclass:
  class: ...\MyClass
  arguments: ["@service_container"]
```